# Convert data types within a custom function

Tags: function, google-sheets, type-conversion, duration

I have a Google Spreadsheets I have been using to keep track of my hours worked at my job.  I am trying to create a custom function to calculate my total hours for the week.  Say I work 6 hours of overtime, but then take Friday off.  My regular hours would be 32, and I would have 6 hours or overtime. In the event that I don't work 40 hours, I would like to adjust my total hours by taking from any overtime hours and adding to my regular hours.

I have come up with the following function, but I have not yet been able to make it work.  I believe I am running into a problem with data types (the inputs are Durations), but I'm not sure how to resolve it.  I am dividing by 24 because that seems to convert the values from Duration to Number, but I still can't get it to return the correct answer.

```
function calcAdjRegHours(regHours, otHours) {
  if(regHours<(40/24)); 
  {
    if(otHours>(0/24)); 
    {
      if((regHours + otHours)>(40/24)); 
      {
        var diff = (40/24) - regHours;
        regHours += diff;        
        return regHours;        
      } elseif; {
        return "regHours + otHours is less than 40";
      }
    } elseif; {
      return "there are no otHours";
    }
  } elseif; {
    return "regHours is greater than 40";
  }
}
```

What am I overlooking, or am I making this overly complicated?

Edit:  When I call this function with inputs of 40:00, and 2:00, I get the value:

Sun Dec 31 1899 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)2208988800001.6665.

If I run this function:

`function calcAdjRegHours(regHours, otHours) {
  return ((regHours*24 + otHours*24)/24);
}`

I get: -4418114400000.

If I use "return (regHours + otHours);", I get:

Sun Dec 31 1899 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)Sat Dec 30 1899 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST).

Something is going wrong when I try to add the variables.  They are formatted as Duration, and from my research I can/need to convert them to do arithmetic.  I did that by multiplying the variables by 24, adding, and then dividing by 24 again to get it back to a duration.

Comment: That worked!  I had to change some formatting since I am using the Duration number format.  I ended up with 

=if(F14<(40/24), (F14+G14), if(F14=(40/24), F14, F14-(40/24)))

I would still like to know why my function wasn't working, but I guess it will be left a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using: =if(F14<(40/24), (F14+G14), if(F14=(40/24), F14, F14-(40/24))).  That did the trick, although I would still like to come up with a custom function that would do it a little more nicely.